# How to get a black screen from boot, until a script ask to turn on display?

Tags: linux, display

For a "Smart Mirror" I made, I'd like to hide the boot process because this is ugly.
I use Debian and XFCE (I can use another DM in place of XFCE).

Ideally the screen remain blank until the apps are launched.

I already hidden BIOS (a little tricky) and GRUB (easy).
I can turn off the console with `setterm -blank force` when Linux start, but as soon as X start the screen come back. I then have to reblank it with `xset dmps force off` until I decide every application are started. But between console and X there something displayed for more than 4 seconds (the computer is slow).

--> how can I keep the screen black from boot until when I decide?

Maybe there is a way to have the monitor turned off with a kernel parameter?
Or a way to keep a black bitmap on the screen?
Or a way to start X on a virtual screen then transfer it to the real scren?

Comment: For X11 to turn video off see `xset dpms force off`.

Comment: What about redirecting the console output to a serial port? https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/5-linux-unix-commands-for-connecting-to-the-serial-console/